# dc.js - apply filter on click of a button

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Anyone know how to apply filter to the charts on a click of a button? Say I already have the object that consist of dimensions and filters from doing saved searches, now I want to apply that filter on a click of a button.

I'm doing this in Angular, I'm trying to create a service that can be use to apply filter to all my charts.

This is what I've tried so far:

I have a component that holds all the chart

```
            this.patients = v;
        this.ndx = crossfilter(this.patients);
        this.cs.samplesGroup = this.ndx.dimension((d) => {
            return d.sampleId;
        }, true).group();

        const all = this.ndx.groupAll();

        var genderDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.gender;})
        var genderGroup = genderDim.group();

        var conditionDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ 
            return d.conditions;
        });
        var conditionGroup = conditionDim.groupAll().reduce(this.reduceAdd, this.reduceRemove, this.reduceInitial).value();
        conditionGroup.all = function() {
            var newObject = [];
            for (var key in this) {
              if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "all") {
                newObject.push({
                  key: key,
                  value: this[key],
                });
              }
            }
            return newObject;
          }

        var conditionDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ 
            return d.conditions;
        });

        var alanineInCerebralSpinalFluidDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.alanineInCerebralSpinalFluid;});
        var alanineInCerebralSpinalFluidGroup = alanineInCerebralSpinalFluidDim.group();

        var lactateInCerebralSpinalFluidDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.lactateInCerebralSpinalFluid;});
        var lactateInCerebralSpinalFluidGroup = lactateInCerebralSpinalFluidDim.group();

        var alanineInSerumOrPlasmaDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.alanineInSerumOrPlasma;});
        var alanineInSerumOrPlasmaGroup = alanineInSerumOrPlasmaDim.group();

        var lactateInVenousBloodDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.lactateInVenousBlood;});
        var lactateInVenousBloodGroup = lactateInVenousBloodDim.group();

        var choiceDilatedDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.choiceDilated;});
        var choiceDilatedGroup = choiceDilatedDim.group();

        var choiceHyperthrophicDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.choiceHyperthrophic;});
        var choiceHyperthrophicGroup = choiceHyperthrophicDim.group();

        var choiceLeftVentricularNonCompactionDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.choiceLeftVentricularNonCompaction;});
        var choiceLeftVentricularNonCompactionGroup = choiceLeftVentricularNonCompactionDim.group();

        var choiceEndocardialFibroElastosisDim = this.ndx.dimension(function(d){ return d.choiceEndocardialFibroElastosis;});
        var choiceEndocardialFibroElastosisGroup = choiceEndocardialFibroElastosisDim.group();

        this.charts = [
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'gender',
                'pie',
                genderDim,
                340,
                200,
                true,
                genderGroup,
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'alanineInCerebralSpinalFluid',
                'bar',
                alanineInCerebralSpinalFluidDim,
                340,
                200,
                true,
                alanineInCerebralSpinalFluidGroup,
                null,
                'Alanine [Moles/volume] in Cerebral spinal fluid',
                '# Samples',
            ),      
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'lactateInCerebralSpinalFluid',
                'bar',
                lactateInCerebralSpinalFluidDim,
                340,
                200,
                true,
                lactateInCerebralSpinalFluidGroup,
                null,
                'Lactate [Moles/volume] in Cerebral spinal fluid',
                '# Samples',
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'alanineInSerumOrPlasma',
                'bar',
                alanineInSerumOrPlasmaDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                alanineInSerumOrPlasmaGroup,
                null,
                'Alanine [Moles/volume] in Serum or Plasma',
                '# Samples',
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'lactateInVenousBlood',
                'bar',
                lactateInVenousBloodDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                lactateInVenousBloodGroup,
                null,
                'Lactate [Moles/volume] in Venous blood',
                '# Samples',
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'choiceDilated',
                'pie',
                choiceDilatedDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                choiceDilatedGroup,
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'choiceHyperthrophic',
                'pie',
                choiceHyperthrophicDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                choiceHyperthrophicGroup,
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'choiceLeftVentricularNonCompaction',
                'pie',
                choiceLeftVentricularNonCompactionDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                choiceLeftVentricularNonCompactionGroup,
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'choiceEndocardialFibroElastosis',
                'pie',
                choiceEndocardialFibroElastosisDim,
                340,
                200,
                false,
                choiceEndocardialFibroElastosisGroup,
            ),
            new MitochondriaChart(
                'conditions',
                'row',
                conditionDim,
                1050,
                800,
                true,
                conditionGroup,
                (dimension, filters) => {
                    dimension.filter(null);   
                    if (filters.length === 0)
                        dimension.filter(null);
                    else
                        dimension.filterFunction(function (d) {
                            if (difference(filters, d).length === 0) return true;
                            return false; 
                        });
                    return filters;  
                },
            ),

        ];

        dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count')
        .dimension(this.ndx)
        .group(all);

        dc.renderAll();
```

then I have the chart component itself:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.data.type === "row") {
        this.initRowChart();
    } else if (this.data.type === "pie"){
        this.initPie();
    }else if (this.data.type === "bar"){
        this.initBarChart();
    }

    this.chart.on("filtered", (c) => {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
        this.cs.changes.next();
        this.ClinicalFilterService.setFilters(this.data.name, this.chart.filters());
    });

    this.chart.render();
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}

initPie() {
    this.chart = dc.pieChart(`.chart .${this.data.name}`)
        .width(this.data.width)
        .height(this.data.height)
        .innerRadius(30)
        .slicesCap(10)
        .dimension(this.data.dim)
        .group(this.data.group)
        .title(() => this.data.name);
    if(this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name] !== undefined){
        this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name].forEach(filter => {
            this.chart.filter(filter);
        })
    }      
    if (this.data.filterHandler !== null) {
        this.chart.filterHandler(this.data.filterHandler);
    }
}

initRowChart() {
    this.chart = dc.rowChart(`.chart .${this.data.name}`)                                                                           
                .width(this.data.width)
                .height(this.data.height)
                .group(this.data.group)
                .elasticX(true)
                .ordering(function(d){
                    let i = 0;
                    if(CONDITION_GROUPING[0].includes(d.key))
                        return i++;                       
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[1].includes(d.key))
                        return 25 + i++;
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[2].includes(d.key))
                        return 50 + i++;
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[3].includes(d.key))
                        return 100 + i++;
                })
                .dimension(this.data.dim)
                .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["a","b","c","d"])
                                .range(["#d6e8f5","#85bae0", "#348ccb", "#25628e"]))
                .colorAccessor(function(d) { 
                    if(CONDITION_GROUPING[0].includes(d.key)) 
                        return "a";
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[1]. includes(d.key))
                        return "b";
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[2]. includes(d.key))
                        return "c";
                    else if(CONDITION_GROUPING[3]. includes(d.key))
                        return "d";
                    });
    if(this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name]){
        this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name].forEach(filter => {
            this.chart.filter(filter);
        })
    }        
    if (this.data.filterHandler !== null) {
        this.chart.filterHandler(this.data.filterHandler);
    }
}

initBarChart() {
    this.chart = dc.barChart(`.chart .${this.data.name}`)
        .width(this.data.width)
        .height(this.data.height)
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
        .elasticY(true)
        .yAxisLabel(this.data.yAxisLabel)
        .xAxisLabel(this.data.xAxisLabel)
        .dimension(this.data.dim)
        .group(this.data.group);


    this.chart.yAxis().ticks(3);
    if(this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name]){
        this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name].forEach(filter => {
            this.chart.filter(filter);
        })
    }
    if (this.data.filterHandler !== null) {
        this.chart.filterHandler(this.data.filterHandler);
    }
}
```

Now I tried making a service that will hold the filter object, and as I changed it I want to be applied to the charts I have.

```
private filtersSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
filters = this.filtersSource.asObservable();
chart: crossfilter.baseMixin;

private savedSearchesSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
savedSearches = this.savedSearchesSource.asObservable();

setFilters(name, filter){
    let currentFilter = this.filtersSource.getValue();
    let newFilter = Object.assign({}, currentFilter, {[name]: filter});
    if(newFilter[name].length === 0){
        delete newFilter[name];
    }
    this.filtersSource.next(newFilter);
}

deleteFilter(name){
    let currentFilter = this.filtersSource.getValue();
    let newFilter = Object.assign({}, currentFilter);
    delete newFilter[name];
    this.filtersSource.next(newFilter);
}

clearFilters(){
    this.filtersSource.next({});
}

saveSearches(name){
    let currentSavedSearches = Object.assign({}, this.savedSearchesSource.getValue());
    let currentFilter = Object.assign({}, this.filtersSource.getValue());
    currentSavedSearches[name] = currentFilter;
    this.savedSearchesSource.next(currentSavedSearches);
}

applySavedSearches(savedFilterName) {
    let savedSearches = Object.assign({}, this.savedSearchesSource.getValue()[savedFilterName]);
    this.filtersSource.next(savedSearches);
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.filtersSource.next({})
}
```

I don't know how to get the filters I have on the service to be applied to the charts component I have

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what problem you are having when applying filters, but this code looks problematic:

```
if(this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name]){
    this.ClinicalFilterService.filters[this.data.name].forEach(filter => {
        this.chart.filter(filter);
    })
}
```

This may work because `chart.filter(value)` will toggle that value in and out of the filter set. But it's potentially inefficient to change the filter so many times.

The [syntax for applying multiple filters](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filter__anchor) is a little weird:

```
chart.filter([[value,value,value]]);
```

Yes, an array containing a single array containing the values. Don't ask why.

Actually, that will toggle each of the values as if you had clicked on each one. So `replaceFilter` is probably what you want:

```
chart.replaceFilter([[value,value,value]]);
```

Then you just need to call

```
chart.redrawGroup();
```

to apply the filter changes to all the charts in the group.